# Regex to match URL where scheme is optional (without "http")

Tags: regex

I am using the following regex to match a URL:

```
$search  = "/([\S]+\.(MUSEUM|TRAVEL|AERO|ARPA|ASIA|COOP|INFO|NAME|BIZ|CAT|COM|INT|JOBS|NET|ORG|PRO|TEL|AC|AD|AE|AF|AG|AI|AL|AM|AN|AO|AQ|AR|AS|AT|AU|au|AW|AX|AZ|BA|BB|BD|BE|BF|BG|BH|BI|BJ|BL|BM|BN|BO|BR|BS|BT|BV|BW|BY|BZ|CA|CC|CD|CF|CG|CH|CI|CK|CL|CM|CN|CO|CR|CU|CV|CX|CY|CZ|DE|DJ|DK|DM|DO|DZ|EC|EDU|EE|EG|EH|ER|ES|ET|EU|FI|FJ|FK|FM|FO|FR|GA|GB|GD|GE|GF|GG|GH|GI|GL|GM|GN|GOV|GP|GQ|GR|GS|GT|GU|GW|GY|HK|HM|HN|HR|HT|HU|ID|IE|IL|IM|IN|IO|IQ|IR|IS|IT|JE|JM|JO|JP|KE|KG|KH|KI|KM|KN|KP|KR|KW|KY|KZ|LA|LB|LC|LI|LK|LR|LS|LT|LU|LV|LY|MA|MC|MD|ME|MF|MG|MH|MIL|MK|ML|MM|MN|MO|MOBI|MP|MQ|MR|MS|MT|MU|MV|MW|MX|MY|MZ|NA|NC|NE|NF|NG|NI|NL|NO|NP|NR|NU|NZ|OM|PA|PE|PF|PG|PH|PK|PL|PM|PN|PR|PS|PT|PW|PY|QA|RE|RO|RS|RU|RW|SA|SB|SC|SD|SE|SG|SH|SI|SJ|SK|SL|SM|SN|SO|SR|ST|SU|SV|SY|SZ|TC|TD|TF|TG|TH|TJ|TK|TL|TM|TN|TO|R|H|TP|TR|TT|TV|TW|TZ|UA|UG|UK|UM|US|UY|UZ|VA|VC|VE|VG|VI|VN|VU|WF|WS|YE|YT|YU|ZA|ZM|ZW)([\S]*))/i";
```

But its a bit screwed up because it also matches "example.php" which I dont want. and something like abc...test. I want it to match example.com though. and [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as well as http://example.com.

It just needs a slight tweak at the end but I am not sure what. (there should be a slash after the any domain name which it is not checking for right now and it is only checking \S)

thank you for your time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
$search  = "#^((?#
    the scheme:
  )(?:https?://)(?#
    second level domains and beyond:
  )(?:[\S]+\.)+((?#
    top level domains:
  )MUSEUM|TRAVEL|AERO|ARPA|ASIA|EDU|GOV|MIL|MOBI|(?#
  )COOP|INFO|NAME|BIZ|CAT|COM|INT|JOBS|NET|ORG|PRO|TEL|(?#
  )A[CDEFGILMNOQRSTUWXZ]|B[ABDEFGHIJLMNORSTVWYZ]|(?#
  )C[ACDFGHIKLMNORUVXYZ]|D[EJKMOZ]|(?#
  )E[CEGHRSTU]|F[IJKMOR]|G[ABDEFGHILMNPQRSTUWY]|(?#
  )H[KMNRTU]|I[DELMNOQRST]|J[EMOP]|(?#
  )K[EGHIMNPRWYZ]|L[ABCIKRSTUVY]|M[ACDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]|(?#
  )N[ACEFGILOPRUZ]|OM|P[AEFGHKLMNRSTWY]|QA|R[EOSUW]|(?#
  )S[ABCDEGHIJKLMNORTUVYZ]|T[CDFGHJKLMNOPRTVWZ]|(?#
  )U[AGKMSYZ]|V[ACEGINU]|W[FS]|Y[ETU]|Z[AMW])(?#
    the path, can be there or not:
  )(/[a-z0-9\._/~%\-\+&\#\?!=\(\)@]*)?)$#i";
```

Just cleaned up a bit. This will match *only* HTTP(s) addresses, and, as long as you copied all top level domains correctly from IANA, only those standardized (it will *not* match `http://localhost`) and *with* the `http://` declared.

Finally you should end with the path part, that will always start with a /, if it is there.

However, I'd suggest to follow Cerebrus: If you're not sure about this, learn regexps in a more gentle way and use proven patterns for complicated tasks.

Cheers,

**By the way:** Your regexp will also match `something.r` and `something.h` (between |TO| and |TR| in your example). I left them out in my version, as I guess it was a typo.

**On re-reading the question:** Change

```
  )(?:https?://)(?#
```

to

```
  )(?:https?://)?(?#
```

(there is a `?` extra) to match 'URLs' without the scheme.

Comment: but i dont want the http:// in the beginning to compulsory. as i want it to match "abc.com" also.

Comment: can you please improve [\S]* to probably no spaces + only words + only numbers or whatever that is allowed in a URL?

Comment: \S should never match spaces... I updated it to what Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/How_to_edit#Links_and_URLs allows in it's URLs. That looks reasonable.

Comment: :-) Yeah, and unfortunately all the other generic TLDs. This will make automated link detection without natural language processing near impossible...

Comment: Yeah I doubt this will catch all the open domain tlds like big.wong

Comment: @Eddie for your consideration: the answer is from '09, the comment from '11. In natural language you’d want to detect IRIs as well, which will come dangerously close to the useless `/\w+\.\w+/u`. What will we do then? Last resort is natural language processing and trying to parse the text to get a grasp of the meaning.

Comment: @Boldewyn Tell me, please, by which process/tooling did you construct the "MUSEUM"…"Z[AMW]" portion? I presume it was not by hand? It's quite impressive.

Comment: It would be nice for the regexp to also enforce maximum length(s) for the domain name, vis-à-vis https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/16996

Comment: When I compiled the list in 2009 there were no new-style generic TLDs like .google or .books, so, yes, I compiled it by hand. This means, too, that the regexp is now outdated, since it won’t match any of the newer TLDs. I’d suggest taking a pragmatic `\.[a-z]+` approach instead of trying to stay on top of newly defined TLDs. About the max-length: replace `+` with `{1,63}`. That does the `label` part. The 253 char total part needs to be done separately, though.

Answer (score 12):

Not exactly what the OP asked for but this is a much simpler regular expression that does not need to be updated each time the IANA introduces a new TLD. I believe this is more adequate for most simple needs:

```
^(?:https?://)?(?:[\w]+\.)(?:\.?[\w]{2,})+$
```

no list of TLD, localhost is not matched, the number of subparts must be >= 2 and the length of each subpart must be >= 2 (fx: "a.a" will not match but "a.ab" will match).

Comment: So this does not match the path & query param part of url?

Comment: Also fails to match hyphens in the URL.

Comment: You need to escape slashes in `https?://` but still it's too broad. You can test it here: http://www.regexr.com/

Comment: It doesn't seem to match subdomains e.g. https://consent.cookiebot.com

Answer (score 8):

This question was surprisingly difficult to find an answer for. The regexes I found were too complicated to understand, and anything more that a regex is overkill and too difficult to implement.

Finally came up with:

```
/(\S+\.(com|net|org|edu|gov)(\/\S+)?)/
```

Works with `http://example.com`, `https://example.com`, `example.com`, `http://example.com/foo`.

Explanation:

- Looks for .com, etc.
- Matches everything before it up to the space
- Matches everything after it up to the space

Comment: That will also match if a string like ".com" occurs but is not part of the domain, like in "http://example.zork/foo/.com/bar", and omits all the county-specific top-level domains (like .uk, .ca, etc) and others.

Comment: +1 for letting you choose which domains you'd like to accept, although I would make sure to point that out.
.           .
adding a word boundary (\b) after the domains prevents hits that match the domain but keep extending, like example.commerce or example.governance
.           .
/(\S+\.(com|net|org|edu|gov)\b(\/\S+)?)/

Answer (score 6):

This will get any url in its entirety, including ?= and #/ if they exist:

```
/[A-Za-z]+:\/\/[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\.[A-Za-z0-9\-_:%&;\?\#\/.=]+/g
```

Comment: Also matches `hap://foo.com/` :)

Comment: This omits a few permitted characters, such as apostrophe, !, double-quote, and plus; and % should only be allowed if followed by 2 hex digits. Not to mention internationalized URIS (IRIs)/.

Answer (score 1):

Using a single regexp to match an URL string makes the code incredible unreadable. I'd suggest to use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to split the URL into its components (which is not a trivial task), and check each part with a regexp.

Answer (score 1):

Changing the end of the regex to `(/\S*)?)$` should solve your problem.

To explain what that is doing -

- it is looking for `/` followed by some characters (not whitespace)
- this match is optional, `?` indicated 0 or 1 times
- and finally it should be followed by a end of string (or change it to `\b` for matching on a word boundary).

Answer (score 1):

I think this is simple and efficient  `/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/`

Answer (score 0):

$ : The dollar signifies the end of the string. 
For example \d*$ will match strings which end with a digit.
So you need to add the $!

Answer (score 0):

Regex to match all urls (with www, without www, with http or https, without http or https, includes all 2-6 letter top level domain names [for countries, ex 'ly','us'], ports, query strings, and anchors ['#']).
It's not 100% but it is better than anything I have seen posted on the web.

It uses the top level domains from the first answer, combined with other techniques found in my searches. It will return any valid url that has bounds, that is where \b comes into play. Since the trailing '/' is also triggered by \b, the last one, is a match for one or more '?'.

```
/\b((http(s?):\/\/)?([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+(MUSEUM|TRAVEL|AERO|ARPA|ASIA|EDU|GOV|MIL|MOBI|COOP|INFO|NAME|BIZ|CAT|COM|INT|JOBS|NET|ORG|PRO|TEL|A[CDEFGILMNOQRSTUWXZ]|B[ABDEFGHIJLMNORSTVWYZ]|C[ACDFGHIKLMNORUVXYZ]|D[EJKMOZ]|E[CEGHRSTU]|F[IJKMOR]|G[ABDEFGHILMNPQRSTUWY]|H[KMNRTU]|I[DELMNOQRST]|J[EMOP]|K[EGHIMNPRWYZ]|L[ABCIKRSTUVY]|M[ACDEFGHKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ]|N[ACEFGILOPRUZ]|OM|P[AEFGHKLMNRSTWY]|QA|R[EOSUW]|S[ABCDEGHIJKLMNORTUVYZ]|T[CDFGHJKLMNOPRTVWZ]|U[AGKMSYZ]|V[ACEGINU]|W[FS]|Y[ETU]|Z[AMW])(:[0-9]{1,5})?((\/([a-z0-9_\-\.~]*)*)?((\/)?\?[a-z0-9+_\-\.%=&amp;]*)?)?(#[a-zA-Z0-9!$&'()*+.=-_~:@/?]*)?)/gi
```

Comment: What does "/?" mean near the end of the regex? Did you mean "\/?"

Comment: Doesn't appear to work for things like "http://s3.amazonaws.com/plivocloud/4c743546-7e1b-11e2-9060-002590662312.mp3"

Answer (score 0):

This is THE ONE:

```
_^(?:(?:https?|ftp)://)(?:\S+(?::\S*)?@)?(?:(?!10(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!127(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})(?!169\.254(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!192\.168(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?!172\.(?:1[6-9]|2\d|3[0-1])(?:\.\d{1,3}){2})(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[01]\d|22[0-3])(?:\.(?:1?\d{1,2}|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])){2}(?:\.(?:[1-9]\d?|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-4]))|(?:(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+-?)*[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}0-9]+)*(?:\.(?:[a-z\x{00a1}-\x{ffff}]{2,})))(?::\d{2,5})?(?:/[^\s]*)?$_iuS
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [Regexy::Web::Url](https://github.com/vladimir-tikhonov/regexy#regexyweburl)

`r = Regexy::Web::Url.new # matches 'http://foo.com', 'www.foo.com' and 'foo.com'`

Answer (score -1):

```
[ftp:\/\/www\/.-https:\/\/-http:\/\/][a-zA-Z0-9u00a1-uffff0]{1,3}[^ ]{1,1000}
```

This works fine for me in js

```
var regex = new RegExp('[ftp:\/\/www\/.-https:\/\/-http:\/\/][a-zA-Z0-9u00a1-uffff0]{1,3}[^ ]{1,1000}');
regex.exec('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FM7MFYoylVs&feature=youtu.be&t=20s');
```

Comment: can you format your answer better? It's very difficult to understand.

Answer (score -2):

Just to add to things.  I know this doesn't fully and directly answer this specific question, but it's the best place I can find to add this info.  I wrote a jQuery plug a while back to match urls for similar purpose, however at current state (will update it as time goes on) it will still consider addresses like 'http://abc.php' as valid.  However, if there is no http, https, or ftp at url start, it will not return 'valid'.  Though I should clarify, this jQuery method returns an object and not just one string or boolean.  The object breaks things down and among the breakdown is a .valid boolean.  See the full fiddle and test in the link at bottom.  If you simply wanna grab the plugin and go, see below:

> jQuery Plugin

```
(function($){$.matchUrl||$.extend({matchUrl:function(c){var b=void 0,d="url,,scheme,,authority,path,,query,,fragment".split(","),e=/^(([^\:\/\?\#]+)\:)?(\/\/([^\/\?\#]*))?([^\?\#]*)(\?([^\#]*))?(\#(.*))?/,a={url:void 0,scheme:void 0,authority:void 0,path:void 0,query:void 0,fragment:void 0,valid:!1};"string"===typeof c&&""!=c&&(b=c.match(e));if("object"===typeof b)for(x in b)d[x]&&""!=d[x]&&(a[d[x]]=b[x]);a.scheme&&a.authority&&(a.valid=!0);return a}});})(jQuery);
```

> jsFiddle with example:

http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/e4Ank/

Answer (score -3):

`(http|www)\S+`

Just use this regex to match all url's

Comment: This is a really bad regular expression. I can't believe people actually voted for it. It is bad because it will also match completely invalid `httpcheese` as a valid url.