# regex to remove URL from text

Tags: python, regex, url

I want to remove all occurrences of URL [full path, query string] from the text in Python. Any suggestions on how to do this? I am new to regex!

```
http://example.com/url/?x=data
```

This whole URL should be removed!
Thanks

Comment: What appears outside of the url? Will it always end with double or single quotes, for example? Or a space?

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely a non-trivial task assuming you want to remove any valid URL.  I'd take a look at the Regex Lib [page on the topic](http://regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=URL).

Answer (score 1):

[This previous question will get you off to a good start to match the URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url), (ie. [RegExLib.com](http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=1&categoryId=2)) then its just a matter of the removal

Answer (score -1):

[URL remove Example](http://shellykaohsiung.blogspot.tw/2016/07/regular-expression-to-url-removed-in-php.html)

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/<a.*?href=".*?">(.*?)<[\/]a>/', $content,$arr);

    $new_content = str_replace($arr[0], $arr[1], $content);
    echo $new_content;
?>
```