# Extract string from string using RegEx in the Terminal

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a **string** like `first url, second url, third url` and would like to extract only the `url` after the word `second` in the OS X Terminal (only the first occurrence). How can I do it?

In *my favorite editor* I used the regex `/second (url)/` and used `$1` to extract it, I just don't know how to do it in the Terminal.

Keep in mind that `url` is an actual url, I'll be using one of these expressions to match it: [Regex to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)

Answer (score 74, accepted):

```
echo 'first url, second url, third url' | sed 's/.*second//'
```

Edit: I misunderstood. Better:

```
echo 'first url, second url, third url' | sed 's/.*second \([^ ]*\).*/\1/'
```

or:

```
echo 'first url, second url, third url' | perl -nle 'm/second ([^ ]*)/; print $1'
```

Comment: That returns ` url, third url` =/

Comment: The third command works best (no need to escape parenthesis and such = great) but it returns all the occurrences (with my input, a long file, 13 times each), I would just need the first

Comment: I added an inelegant `| sed -n '1 s/\./\./p'` after the perl command and everything worked out fine =D

Thank you!

Comment: where can I see what the options -nle mean?

Comment: [Perl One Liners](http://novosial.org/perl/one-liner/)

Comment: @bfred.it Pass `-E` or `-r` to `sed`, and you don't need to escape parenthesis.

Answer (score 46):

Piping to another process (like 'sed' and 'perl' suggested above) might be very expensive, especially when you need to run this operation multiple times. Bash does support regexp:

[[[ "string" =~ regex ]]](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs)

Similarly to the way you extract matches in your favourite editor by using `$1`, `$2`, etc., Bash fills in the `$BASH_REMATCH` array with all the matches.

In your particular example:

```
str="first url1, second url2, third url3"
if [[ $str =~ (second )([^,]*) ]]; then
  echo "match: '${BASH_REMATCH[2]}'"
else
  echo "no match found"
fi
```

Output:

```
match: 'url2'
```

Specifically, `=~` supports *extended* regular expressions [as defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), but with *platform-specific extensions* (which vary in extent and can be incompatible).
On Linux platforms (GNU userland), see `man grep`; on macOS/BSD platforms, see `man re_format`.

Comment: Why would you state that "piping to another process might be very expensive"?

Comment: @akauppi, there's a cost to start a new process (OS must allocate lots of things, run some checks, setup environment, do some disk IO, switch context, etc. etc. Then after your external process is done there's some extra cleanup as well). For simplicity lets benchmark. We'll process 14 thousand lines CSV ascii file. Using "bash support regexp" it takes 1 second! and if I iterate lines and call "sed" for each line then it takes 42 seconds. I need to process 1.4M lines, so it would make it: 100seconds "bash way" vs 1 hour 10 min piping to "sed"! Feel the difference! (c)    :)

Comment: You convinced me to revisit a code I did this week. :)

Answer (score 12):

In the other answer provided you still remain with everything after the desired URL. So I propose you the following solution.

```
echo 'first url, second url, third url' | sed 's/.*second \(url\)*.*/\1/'
```

Under sed you group an expression by escaping the parenthesis around it (POSIX standard).

Answer (score 7):

**While trying this, what you probably forgot was the `-E` argument for `sed`.**

From `sed --help`:

```
  -E, -r, --regexp-extended
                 use extended regular expressions in the script
                 (for portability use POSIX -E).
```

You don't have to change your regex significantly, but you do need to add `.*` to match greedily around it to remove the other part of string.

This works fine for me:

```
echo "first url, second url, third url" | sed -E 's/.*second (url).*/\1/'
```

Output:

```
url
```

In which the output "url" is actually the second instance in the string. But if you already know that it is formatted in between comma and space, and you don't allow these characters in URLs, then the regex `[^,]*` should be fine.

Optionally:

```
echo "first http://test.url/1, second ://test.url/with spaces/2, third ftp://test.url/3" \
     | sed -E 's/.*second ([a-zA-Z]*:\/\/[^,]*).*/\1/'
```

Which correctly outputs:

```
://example.com/with spaces/2
```