# How to extract part of string in Bash using regex

Tags: regex, sed

I have been trying to extract part of string in bash. I'm using it on Mac.

Pattern of input string:

- Some random word follow by a `/`. This is optional.
- Keyword (`def`, `foo`, and `bar`) followed by hyphen(`-`) followed by numbers. This can be 2-6 digit numbers
- These numbers are followed by hyphens again and few hyphen separated words.

#### Sample inputs and outputs:

```
abc/def-1234-random-words // def-1234
bla/foo-12-random-words // foo-12
bar-12345-random-words // bar-12345
```

So I tried following command to fetch it but for some weird reason, it returns entire string.

```
extractedValue=`getInputString | sed -e 's/.*\(\(def\|bar\|foo\)-[^-]*\).*/\1/g'`
// and
extractedValue=`getInputString | sed -e 's/.*\(\(def\|bar\|foo\)-\d{2,6}\).*/\1/g'`
```

I also tried to make it case-insensitive using `I` flag but it threw error for me:

> : bad flag in substitute command: 'I'

---

Following are the references I tried:

- [Extract substring using regexp in plain bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13373249/extract-substring-using-regexp-in-plain-bash)
- [Extract string from string using RegEx in the Terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3532718/extract-string-from-string-using-regex-in-the-terminal)

Comment: `sed` doesn't support `\d` for digits, you can use `[0-9]`

Comment: @Barmar i noticed some weird behaviour around `\d`. Hence i moved to `[^-]*`. It used to match it but always returned entire string. But I'll read more about it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `gnu sed` should work with ignore case flag:

```sh
sed -E 's~^(.*/){0,1}((def|foo|bar)-[0-9]{2,6})-.*~\2~I' file

def-1234
foo-12
bar-12345
```

This sed matches:

- `(.*/){0,1}`: Match a string upto `/` optionally at the start
- `(`: Start capture group #2

  - `(def|foo|bar)`: Match `def` or `foo` or `bar`
  - `-`: Match a `-`
  - `[0-9]{2,6}`: Match 2 to 6 digits
- `)`: End capture group #2
- `-.*`: Match `-` followed by anything till end
- Substitution is value we capture in group #2

---

Or you may use this `awk`:

```sh
awk -v IGNORECASE=1 -F / 'match($NF, /^(def|foo|bar)-[0-9]{2,6}-/) {print substr($NF, 1, RLENGTH-1)}' file

def-1234
foo-12
bar-12345
```

**Awk explanation:**

- `-v IGNORECASE=1`: Enable ignore case matching
- `-F /`: Use `/` as field separator
- `match($NF, /^(def|foo|bar)-[0-9]{2,6}-/)`: Match text using regex `^(def|foo|bar)-[0-9]{2,6}-` in `$NF` which is last field using `/` as field separator (to ignore text before `/`)
- If match is successful then using `substr` print text from position  `1` to `RLENGTH-1` (since we matching until `-` after digits)

Comment: Could you please also add explanation? What $NF means and is this case sensitive?

Comment: I am going to add. Meanwhile check `sed` which will do ignore case matchig

Comment: Weird thing is, sed approach is still throwing this error: **: bad flag in substitute command: 'I'**. Is it environment specific? I'm using ZSH over Mac terminal

Comment: Yes as I mentioned that requires gnu sed. `sed` on Mac is BSD and that doesn't support `/I`. I am also on Mac but have gnu sed installed using `home brew`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `-E` option to use extended regular expressions, then you don't have to escape `(` and `|`.

```
echo abc/def-1234-random-words  | sed -E -e 's/.*((def|bar|foo)-[^-]*).*/\1/g'
def-1234
```

Comment: This along with `gsed` for case-insensitivity flag `/I` solved my issue. Thanks a TON!

Answer (score 0):

Use `grep` with the `--only-matching` option (shorthand `-o`).

```bash
grep --only-matching --extended-regexp '(foo|bar|def)-[0-9]{2,6}' <<EOF
abc/def-1234-random-words
bla/foo-12-random-words
bar-12345-random-words
EOF
```