# How to execute regex inside a bitbucket pipeline?

Tags: bitbucket, pipeline, bitbucket-pipelines

I have a bitbucket pipeline where I want to retrieve some part of the branch name (the ticket name)

I basically get the branch name with :

```
 - BRANCH_NAME="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
```

Now the branch name is like
`fix/DOM-123-my-ticket-info`

I would like to basically do something like

```
 - BRANCH_NAME="$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)"
 - TICKET_NAME= // a way to retrieve DOM-123 from $BRANCH_NAME
```

Do you know how would this be possible ?

I haven"t find anything on how such a thing would be possible.

Comment: What are the rules for ticket names? No slashes? Are `DOM` and `my-ticket-info` fixed strings?

Comment: This https://stackoverflow.com/q/69468283/11715259 is your actual question, am I wrong?

Comment: probably fine yeah thank you ! ticket name is always after first / and end always after second -

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run a regular expression outside your usual language/runtime, you should get used to the `grep` utility.

A naive approach for your case:

```bash
TICKET_NAME=$(echo $BRANCH_NAME | grep --only-matching --extended-regexp 'DOM-[0-9]+')
```

(you might need to workout the actual ticket name regex)

---

Friendly reminder: the branch name is accessible in the `$BITBUCKET_BRANCH` environment variable (for branch pipelines, no custom nor tag-triggered pipelines)