# How can I find and replace all URL's using regular expressions in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

My URL's might not be well formatted, so it could be `http://www.google.com/` or `www.google.com` or `google.com` and it'll be in a block of text like:

```
This is google.com and it rocks!
```

I need to find the website and replace it with `[*********]`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be useful: http://snipplr.com/view/2371/regex-regular-expression-to-match-a-url/ also this question: [PHP validation/regex for URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this question: [Regex to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)