# Regex for URL Validation

Tags: regex

I have a string which may be an URL. I want to determine if its a Http/FTP URL by a regex. If the string is valid URL then I will make it hyperlink and a blue color etc, if its not an URL based on ture or false of regex exp i want to decide further..

Whats is  best Regex for it ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP validation/regex for URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/206059/php-validation-regex-for-url)

Comment: Have you Googled "URL regular expression"? And what flavor regexp / for which language?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to match URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)

Answer (score 1):

```
 isUrlValid(str)
{
   var pattern = new RegExp('^(https?:\\/\\/)?((([a-z\\d]([a-z\\d-]*[a-z\\d])*)\\.)+[a-z]{2,}|((\\d{1,3}\\.){3}\\d{1,3}))(\\:\\d+)?(\\/[-a-z\\d%_.~+]*)*(\\?[;&a-z\\d%_.~+=-]*)?(\\#[-a-z\\d_]*)?$', 'g'); 
   return pattern.test(str);
}
```

## It passes all this test cases:

- https://saverlife.org - valid
- https://www.google.com - valid
- https:/saverlife.org - invalid
- https:/www.google.com - invalid
- http://saverlife.org - valid
- http://www.google.com - valid
- http:/saverlife org - invalid
- http:/www.google.com - invalid
- saverlife.org - valid
- [www.google.com](http://www.google.com) - valid
- https:/saverlife.org - invalid
- saverlife .org - invalid
- No input - invalid
- links ending with .in,.org - all valid
- https://www.google.com/37$&@82
- https://abc/xyz  - valid (links having slashes ahead after https://)

Answer (score 0):

This perl code is pretty accurate, probably not perfect. Group 1 contains either `http` or `ftp`

```
if ($str =~ /^(http|ftp):\/\/[\w.%@]+(:?[?].*)?/) {
    print "matches $1\n";
} else {
    print "no match\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you want to know if the url really exists:

```
function url_exist($url){//se passar a URL existe
    $c=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_HEADER,1);//get the header
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_NOBODY,1);//and *only* get the header
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);//get the response as a string from curl_exec(), rather than echoing it
    curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT,1);//don't use a cached version of the url
    if(!curl_exec($c)){
        //echo $url.' inexists';
        return false;
    }else{
        //echo $url.' exists';
        return true;
    }
    //$httpcode=curl_getinfo($c,CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    //return ($httpcode<400);
}
```

Comment: How long does that function take?