# Regex expression for url

Tags: javascript

I am pretty new to regex expression 
I need to validate website url with Regex expression through java script
for -- example www.google.com

Http is optional in my case

Please help me out thank you very much

Comment: Possible duplicate of about 100+ other post. You can take almost any url regex that you find suitable for your needs and wrap the scheme with parentheses followed by a question mark. ex. `(https?://)?`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to match URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)

Answer (score 0):

(http|https)://([\w-]+.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?

from: http://www.webpronews.com/validating-a-url-with-regular-expressions-2006-10

Comment: OP says http is optional and yours requires http.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a regex for you that takes into consideration if the URL contains username, if it is an IP, validates general TLDs, and some more.

```
^((http|https|ftp)\://)?([a-zA-Z0-9\.\-]+(\:[a-zA-Z0-9\.&%\$\-]+)*@)*((25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9])\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[1-9]|0)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[0-1]{1}[0-9]{2}|[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}|[0-9])|localhost|([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.(com|edu|gov|int|mil|net|org|biz|arpa|info|name|pro|aero|coop|museum|[a-zA-Z]{2}))(\:[0-9]+)*(/($|[a-zA-Z0-9\.\,\?\'\\\+&%\$#\=~_\-]+))*$
```

Here is how it works: [regex analyzer](http://goo.gl/ECQoy)

This has been taken from [regexlib.com](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=501), and only changed so that the scheme (http, https, etc) part is optional and replaced `&amp;` with `&`.

**Simpler version**

Here is a simpler version, which works well most of the time:

```
^((ftp|http|https):\/\/)?(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?((\S+.[a-z]{2,6})|([0-9\.]+))(:[0-9]+)?(\S+)?$
```

Here is how it works: [regex analyzer](http://goo.gl/MAADb)

In case you´re interested:

Group 2: The scheme (eg. `http`)
Group 3: Username and password (optional)
Group 4: Either hostname or IP
Group 5: If group 4 is hostname, this group is the hostname (eg. `stackoverflow.com`)
Group 6: If group 4 is an IP, this is the IP address
Group 7: Is the port (optional)
Group 8: Is the path and query, actually the rest (eg. `/hello?world=foo`)

Try it out on [regexpal](http://regexpal.com/).