# IE using the bing search

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

How the IE(on windows phone 7) is using the bing search when we simply enter some text on the search textbox and when we enter some URL then it navigates to the web page. How they integrated both in a single textbox? Can anyone help me. Thanks in advance for hard work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe using [SearchTask](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.tasks.searchtask) (MSDN link)?

Comment: Yes, you are right. They may be using search task but how only for words(string), that's my question.

Comment: with a regex expression to identify if it's an url or not - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5600593/regex-expression-for-url