# problem with php regular expression

Tags: php, regex

hi i have a data in below format

`<option value="http://www.torontoairportlimoflatrate.com/aurora-limousine-service.html">Aurora</option>
<option value="http://www.torontoairportlimoflatrate.com/alexandria-limousine-service.html">Alexandria</option>`

i after banging my head on table 10 times figured out to use regular expression below

```
preg_match_all("#>\w*#",$data,$result);
```

This returns the results as below

```
 Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => >Ajax
            [1] => >
            [2] => >Aurora
            [3] => >
            [4] => >Alexandria
            [5] => >
            [6] => >Alliston
```

I only want single array having values i.e.
cities
  [0] => Ajax
  [1] => Aurora
...... so on.

Pleas

Comment: Don't use a regex. Use a HTML parser. See [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Comment: This is a job for an [HTML Parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you'd prefer not to use an HTML parser, you can do it with a regex, but keep in mind that you'll probably need to modify it based on what you'll receive as input in the future. For your specific problem, this is a regex that does the job:

```
<?php
    preg_match_all('/<option\svalue=\"([a-zA-Z0-9-_.\/:]+)\">([a-zA-Z\s]+)<\/option>/', $data, $result);

    var_dump($result[2]);
```

**Note:**

If you want to match every url you should replace `([a-zA-Z0-9-_.\/:]+)` with a more capable url matching regex. You can find [some](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url) on StackOverflow also, but for me is a matter of personal taste.