# Is my regex to validate an URL correct?

Tags: php, regex

I am working on writing a Perl-compatible regular expression in PHP to check whether a given string is a valid URL.

Now currently it works as expected, but I am wondering if there are any precautions I should use to check whether it's safe for user input. The `$url` variable is being submitted as-is, as in plain-text.

Here is the whole function:

```
private function real_url($url) {
    return preg_match("/(http|https):\/\/(.*?)\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}/i",$url);
}
```

I only want it to check for `http` and `https`. I'm not worried about `ftp`, `irc` and the like. Just web links.

It also checks how long the TLD is. `So "google.asdfasdfasdf"` will return `false` but `google.asdf"` will return `true`. How can I fix that? `".asdf"` clearly isn't a valid TLD.

I just need to know two things:

- How to check whether the given URL is actually legitimate;
- Whether it is safe for raw user input.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Regex to match URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)

Comment: Never wrap a RegExp in / especially when validating an URL. Just use '~Regexp Rule~i'. And you will not longer need to escape / with \/. A lot easier to write RegExp rlated to HTML/URLs especially since / is used a lot in these string and patterns.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) instead:

```
private function real_url($url) {
    return filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) !== FALSE;
}
```

Note, this won't validate that the scheme is allowed (such as http/https), nor that the top-level domain exists.

The simplest way of verifying the domain as actually being valid would be to do a DNS lookup, for instance using [`checkdnsrr`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.checkdnsrr.php):

```
private function validate_domain($domain) {
    return checkdnsrr($domain, "A");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That is very helpful!  It just has one problem:  If you use htasfasdftp://google.ca, it will still return true.

Comment: note that your `google.asdf` example would still pass this test.

Comment: @Jaxo yes, because `htasfasdftp` is a  _syntactically legal_, but _unused_ URL scheme.  This is the difference between testing for legal _syntax_ and testing for a _currently valid_ URL.

Comment: Good point. Added a comment on how to check that the domain has a legal suffix.

Comment: @Sebastian No, that's not what the public suffix list is intended for - a simle DNS or HTTP access request would be more reliable and wouldn't depend on keeping an up-to-date suffix list around.

Answer (score 1):

> It also checks how long the .something is. So google.asdfasdfasdf will
>   return false but google.asdf will return true. How can I fix that,
>   because .asdf obviously isn't a domain name.

The *only* way to 100% reliably check whether a given URL is valid is to *try and access it*.

Any other method (e.g. `filter_var`) can only check the validity of the *syntax*, and won't take changes to the DNS into account (e.g. new gTLDs).

Take a look at the `curl` functions within PHP.  Ideally you should combine `filter_var` first (to check the syntax) with an attempt to access the URL to check that the supplied URL actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is rather pointless. Are you aware that currently [**hundreds of extensions** are in process of validation](http://newgtlds.icann.org/en/) and it's impossible to keep up with all.

There are two steps here:

1. One make sure the URL is legal which can be done with a RegExp in a very superficial way. You should combine RegExp with actual code to do it right.
2. Testing the domain name with a DNS query to check if it exists *(does not mean it's functional)*.
3. Test a HEAD request against the actual URL and see how it works. Very difficult for large lists in PHP.

So checkout the **[Public Suffix](http://publicsuffix.org/list/) initiative**. Parse the TLD list. Implement it in your script. And keep up to date :)

Answer (score -1):

The only way to be sure is to query whois servers (or Google site:domain.com) and check if domain exists. `(.*?)` will match almost everything, domain name must be `[a-z0-9\-\_]`, but cannot start with hypen or underscore (you need regex for that also).

@Alnitak

```
    function check($url){
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);
        return $data;
    }

echo check("http://qwertgzhgfdsdfghjhzgtf.com");
```

Will return nothing, else will return headers.

```
echo (check('http://stackoverflow.com') != '')? ':)': ':(';
```

Comment: there are many valid url websites (new or old) that aren't listed in google

Comment: the output of the `whois` protocol is **not** designed to be read by computers.

Comment: @Alnitak Output of cURL can be false even if the domain exist ;) @yes123, just an option.

Comment: @webarto that's my point - `curl` can test not just that the domain exists, but that there's _actually a web page at that location_ !

Comment: @Alnitak, OK for the content, but for existence, no, ideally, combination of all methods would work, but...

Comment: @webarto you should call `curl_getinfo` and check the HTTP response code or check `curl_errno`, not the output of `curl_exec` !!

Comment: @Alnitak, that is just a preference... Your answer doesn't provide any other info besides cURL, feel free to post you solution.

Comment: @webarto no, it's not a "preference", it's good coding - use the functions provided by the API specifically designed to tell you the result of the call.

Comment: @Alnitak, since you are twice my age (if that's real), I won't argue, I know, I understand, but sometimes these answers are not the one OP's are looking for, trust me on that ;)

Comment: I think @webarto is spot on. `filter_var` is totally broken, regex is arbitrary and interpretive ... pinging the web server itself with curl is a definitive test, albeit of a particular moment in time. but what isn't ;)

Comment: @webarto Not down-voting (still tempted) but this has nothing to do with URL validation. A valid URL has nothing to do with a functional website. Imagine sanitizing a list of 10.000 URLs with this method. While a RegExp is easy and works well.

Comment: @Claudrian good luck with that ;) Take a look at the answer below. Feel free to downvote if you, it is your right.

Comment: @webarto I won't but you're use of cURL is missing stuff. You need to use the curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL); to get the URL in case redirections occur, you need to enable redirections too. That gives you the real URL :) You also have to disable SSL verify in cURL just to handle all https URLs properly. And try your technique to sanitize 10.000 URLs in PHP. Ping me when it's done.

Comment: @Claudrian following redirection can lead to some other URL and then you would have false positive or something... I'm not quite familiar with PHP cURL API... One could check URL with filter_var, or check whois, or in the end, try to fetch content... I would use e.g. `curl -i --head http://facebook.com` and parse headers... P.S. I'm sure there is no silver bullet for this, nor did I tried to offer complete solution... Cheers.