# How to remove everything but URL PHP

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)

I know regexp should be able to do this but I can't figure out how to do it. I wan't to be able to search through a string of text and return only the url's. How would you do this in PHP?

## Example

```
hello there everyone visit this link: http://google.com and this one as well http://amazon.com
```

would return:

http://google.com

http://amazon.com

Any ideas?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url

Comment: [URL Regex](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=url%20regex)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$text = "hello there everyone visit this link: http://google.com and this one as well http://amazon.com";
preg_match_all('/\b(([\w-]+:\/\/?|www[.])[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|\/)))/',$text,$matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks, works a charm.  I hate writing regular expression