# PHP Regular expression

Tags: php, regex

Some links like these:

```
[links url='http://www.google.com.hk' title='Google' image='']google[/links]
[links url='http://hk.yahoo.com' title='yahoo' image='']yahoo[/links]
```

how to use PHP Regular expression get the `url` attributes? Thanks.

```
http://www.google.com.hk
http://hk.yahoo.com
```

Comment: May I suggest experimenting in something like http://regexpal.com/

Comment: @Doug T. , no, the url not guaranteed, these just in long text, and I only want to get the `url` attributes?

Comment: @Doug T. I only know simple dom, but this are not regular links. so need for a help.

Comment: @fish If you don't understand regex, getting someone to do it for you won't help you learn.

Comment: Might want to integrate this post into preg_match_all: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url/1141962#1141962][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url/1141962#1141962

Comment: @adlawson sometimes a few good, practical, well-explained examples will help someone learn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
preg_match_all("/\[links[^\]]+url='([^']+)'/", '{{your data}}', $arr, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

Explanation of the regex:

```
/
\[                  //An excaped "[" to make it literal.
links               //The work "links"   
[^\]]+              //1+ non-closing brackent chars ([^] is a negative character class)
url='               //The work url='
([^']+)             //The contents inside the '' in a caputuring group
/
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex: `/\[links\s+(?:[^\]]*\s+)*url=\'([^\']*)\'[^\]]*?\]/`

```
$str = "[links url='http://www.google.com.hk' title='Google' image='']google[/links]";
$m = array();
preg_match('/\[links\s+(?:[^\]]*\s+)*url=\'([^\']*)\'[^\]]*?\]/', $str, $m);
echo $m[1];
```

Comment: Actually, that won't work if url isn't first. Try it against: `[links title='Google' url='http://www.google.com.hk' image='']google[/links]`

Comment: @Jacob You are correct, I forgot a `*`. I fixed it now so that order doesn't matter.