# How to make a link grabbed from a database display as a clickable active link?

Tags: php, mysql, html

I have a form that submits and displays text. Entering `http://www.twitter.com` for example displays in clear text. How can i get it to automatically display as a clickable link?

I am working with MySQL and PHP.

Comment: Write us ur php code and we'll help better.

Comment: What part of wrapping the URL into an `<a>` tag causes your problem?

Comment: bear in mind that this may open your site up to spammers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You propably want your script to automatically detect links...I did that a few weeks ago on a script that pulls tweets from an RSS Feed...this is the code. You can replace $_POST['inputfield'] with the appropriate variable!

```
if (preg_match('/www./',$_POST['inputfield'])) //checks if there's www. in the field. alternatively use http: instead of www.
{
$link_start_pos = strpos($_POST['inputfield'],'www.'); //returns the link-start-pos, alternatively use http: instead of www. 

    // find the end of the link
if($link_end_pos = strpos($_POST['inputfield'], ' ', $link_start_pos) === false) 
    { //if theres no space after the link, it's propably on the end of the text
        $link_end_pos = strlen($_POST['inputfield']); 
    }
    // form a string with the actual link in it
$link = substr($_POST['inputfield'],$link_start_pos,$link_end_pos);
    // and make it clickable
$link_insert = '<a href="'.$link.'" target="_blank">'.$link.'</a>';
}
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Upside with my solution is btw that you can use strpos and the $link_end_pos and $link_start_pos to also output the text after/before the actual link :)

Answer (score 3):

If the data is a URL, you can just wrap it in a tag:

```
printf('<a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>', htmlspecialchars($your_link, ENT_QUOTES));
```

Things get trickier if you need to convert the URL in the text. Most users won't bother with escaping the links correctly, and post `example.com/Some Thing - [Me]` instead of `http://example.com/Some%20Thing%20-%20%5BMe%5D`. Find [a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1141848/427545) that fit your needs and use:

```
echo preg_replace('#expression that matches a URL#', '<a href="$1">$1</a>',
    htmlspecialchars($your_data, ENT_QUOTES));
```

Comment: That's a very clever solution, although it somehow starts the '<a..' too early for some reason in a realworld example (twitter feed) where I just tested it, but that's another topic. What I wanted to add is, that although it's a nice & clean solution, it doesn't allow you to output the text before/after the link, because you don't have a position in the string.

Comment: The first works only if the `$your_link` is a URL. The second needs the data to be grouped, otherwise your get an empty link.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me...

using a DB table with columns "id" "href" "title", as mentioned above by @DarkDevine

```
<div id="buttons">
<ul id="list">
        <?php
        $connect = mysql_connect("host","user","password");
            if(!$connect){
            die("Failed to connect: " . mysql_error());
        }
            if(!mysql_select_db("YOUR DATABASE NAME")){
            die("Failed to select DB:" . mysql_error());
        }
        $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM YOU TABLE NAME");
            while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results)){      
            echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . $row['href'] . '">' .   $row['title'] . '</a>' . '</li>' . '<br/>';
        }   
        ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $result = mysql_query( 'SELECT * FROM `links`' );

 if( mysql_num_rows( $result ) ) {
      foreach( $row = mysql_fetch_object( $result ) ) {
            echo "<a href="{$row->href}">{$row->title}</a>";
      }
 }
```

assuming your table looks like

```
 id href            title
 1  http://google.de    Go to gooogle!
 2  http://twitter.de   Go to twitteeeerr!
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is just an example senario for you to give you an idea of what to do.

Okay lets say we have a form with 1 `textbox` with the name `url` and a submit button, we are also using the `POST` method.

```
<form method="post" action="pageurl.php">
<input type="text" name="url" value="" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

In `pageurl.php` we would then have something like this:

```
<?php

    //Get the value of $_POST['url'] and cleanse it.
    $url = htmlentities(stripslashes(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['url'])));

    //Echo out the click-able link.
    echo '<a href="' . $url . '">' . $url . '</a>';

?>
```

For example if we entered `http://twitter.com` into the form we would get a click-able link with the text `http://twitter.com` which would also link to twitter.com

Answer (score 0):

On the processing page:

```
    <?php
include('config.php');

$link = $_POST['link'];
$title = $_POST['title'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (link) VALUES ('<a href=\'$link\'>$title</a>')";

?>
```

And to retrieve the link:

```
<?php

include('config.php');

//code to select the table

$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

echo "$rows['link']";

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrestled with this for some time before finding the solution that best worked for me. I'll post it as it might help someon else. I am just playing around with a simple URL/Comment PHP script that takes a URL/Comment and inserts to the DB. I then display the results. At first the URLs weren't clickable when displaying. So I set out to find a way to do that. Here's the snippet that worked for me:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td><a href=" . $row['url'] . ">" . $row['url'] . "</a></td>";//this line is it
   echo "<td>" . $row['description'] . "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   }
```

Comment: I should add that there is no exception handling in my script so far. This only works if the URL is entered correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I have no problem with Making link after getting information out of a database. my logic is using `<?php echo '$status'; ?>` So if you say `<a href="http://site.com">Click here</a>` The link will end up inside the echo function. Although if you do it different you might not get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

There is a far easier way to do this.
With a row named "website"

Website: < a href="http://'.$website.'" target="_blank">'.$website.'

the form entry is "www.whateverthewebsiteis.com" and the output would be "http://www.whateverthewebsiteis.com"