# regular expressions how to validate a URL

Tags: javascript, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url)

I wrote a regular expression to validate only the following URL patterns

1. http://www.abc.com
2. www.abc.com
3. abc.com
4. http.www.abc.com

Can anyone give me a regular expression?

There's some error in the regex I used to do it, can anyone fix it?

```
/^((http|http|HTTP|HTTP):\/\/+(www|WWW\.)?[A-Za-z0-9\-\.]{1,}\.[A-Za-z])|((www|WWW\.)?[A-    Za-z0-9\-\.]{1,}\.[A-Za-z])/i.test(value);
```

Comment: What happens when you try it?

Comment: it matched 1,2,3,4 that you mentioned(though I didn't test in javascript). There is an error I suppose, in that 4 shouldn't be matched. But you want it to match 4 it seems. Perhaps you found it didn't match one of those, then show the error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this expression:

```
^(http(?:s)?\:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)*\.[a-zA-Z]{2,6}(?:\/?|(?:\/[\w\-]+)*)(?:\/?|\/\w+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}(?:\?[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)?)?(?:\&[\w]+\=[\w\-]+)*)$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$url = "http://something.com/";
if (preg_match('/^(http|https|ftp)://([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*(?:.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+):?(d+)?/?/i', $url)) {
    echo "Your url is ok.";
} else {
    echo "Wrong url.";
}
```

Comment: well i am looking for javascript  regex. IF we typed abcd.abcd it will fail