# javascript jquery regex for validate a URL

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, url

I'm using following regex for validate a url,

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("url_validation", function (value, element) {
return this.optional(element) || /^(([http|https|HTTPS|HTTP]+:\/\/))?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$/i.test(value);
}, "error");
```

This regex working fine. But when I validate http://www.alfaromeo.com/com/#/home , it says the url is invalid. When I enable #, the regex fail to validate some validations. So, can anyone give a suggestion to modify this regex to validate #, which is inside a url.

I refered [regular expressions how to validate a URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259340/regular-expressions-how-to-validate-a-url) to get this regex.

Thanx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(([http|https|HTTPS|HTTP]+:\/\/))?(([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+(:([\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})+)?@)?([\d\w][-\d\w]{0,253}[\d\w]\.)+[\w]{2,4}(:[\d]+)?(\/([#-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)*(\?(&?([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})=?)*)?(#([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)?$
```

I changed

```
(\/([-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)
```

to

```
(\/([#-+_~.\d\w]|%[a-fA-f\d]{2,2})*)
```

Even so, don't expect it to work on every URL you might throw at it...

Comment: I stole this, and it broke on a comma (,) in the query string.

Comment: As I said, it's likely that it won't work on every possible URL. In my answer I've just modified the regex to work on the URL provided by the OP.