# How to validate url?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to validate urls.
It should accept:

```
http://google.com

http://www.google.com

www.google.com

google.com
```

I refer [Regex to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url) .

But it is not supporting `google.com` .

Comment: You've pointed to a question with several answers. Which regex are *you* using?

Comment: @discky-  I think that your answer lies between both what Tom van der Woerdt and I have recommended.  Tom's suggestion will prepend "http" if it is missing and my suggestion validate's the rest of the url.  The only problem is that if you need "https" or "ftp" then the user needs to specify that so it may be best to validate against them entering the proper prefix to begin with.

Comment: You are using jQuery, and jQuery has URL validation regex routines IIRC

Answer (score 3):

Simply prepend `http://` if it's not there and then test.

```
if (inputURL.substring(0,7) != 'http://' && inputURL.substring(0,8) != 'https://') {
    inputURL = 'http://' + inputURL;
}
```

No large libraries required or anything, just a few lines of code.

Comment: What happens if your URL is less than 7 characters?
'

Answer (score 0):

```
function isUrl(s) {
    var regexp = /(ftp|http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/
    return regexp.test(s);
}
```

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: I'm just saying that this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @TomvanderWoerdt And your comment doesn't answer his. Don't just tell other people "You're wrong," try to explain things in a useful and helpful way.

Answer (score 0):

This is a better way I think should be used to validate urls

```
reg = /https?:\/\/w{0,3}\w*?\.(\w*?\.)?\w{2,3}\S*|www\.(\w*?\.)?\w*?\.\w{2,3}\S*|(\w*?\.)?\w*?\.\w{2,3}[\/\?]\S*/
reg.test('www.google.com')    # will return true
reg.test('www.google')        # will return false
```

Let me know if you still not getting it correct.

Answer (score 0):

This simple helper method uses Regex to validate URLs and will pass on each of your test cases. It also takes into account for whitespace so **google.com/a white space/** will fail.

```
    public static bool ValidateUrl(string value, bool required, int minLength, int maxLength)
    {
        value = value.Trim();
        if (required == false && value == "") return true;
        if (required && value == "") return false;

        Regex pattern = new Regex(@"^(?:http(s)?:\/\/)?[\w.-]+(?:\.[\w\.-]+)+[\w\-\._~:/?#[\]@!\$&'\(\)\*\+,;=.]+$");
        Match match = pattern.Match(value);
        if (match.Success == false) return false;
        return true;
    }
```