# Acknowledge of RegExp

Tags: regex, validation

I need to validate url, so I used site http://www.rubular.com/ and maybe I get wrong result.  So I wrote this: `w{3}\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]{3}` in http://www.rubular.com/ and it gived me almost wanted result. In my model Website I wrote:

```
 VALID_URL_REGEX = /w{3}\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]{3}/
 validates :url, :presence => true, format: { with: VALID_URL_REGEX }
```

Question : how I can make to check, that last part should contain only 3 letters ?

Comment: Why should the last part only contain 3 letters? This answer should give you a 'correct' regex. http://stackoverflow.com/a/1141962/79835

Comment: It's wrong to check that the last part has only three letters. For instance, both `.eu` and `.info` are valid TLDs.

Comment: Your regex has several problems. As others have said it only accepts 3 char tld. it doesn't take into account subdomains other than www, and fails to account for domains like wwww.history.uk.com, it also does not account for other chars which a domin name can have (e.g. - _). You would be better getting an existing regex that has been well tested.

Comment: When I'm doing VALID_URL_REGEX =(here code from  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1141962/79835) but I get error 
A regular expression or a proc or lambda must be supplied as :with.
So how I should change this : validates :url, :presence => true, format: { with: VALID_URL_REGEX } ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `\A` and `\z` to match against start and end of string.

Like this: `/\Aw{3}\.[a-z]+\.[a-z]{3}\z/`.

But like Mahmoud Al-Qudsi said, tlds can have more or less than 3 letters.
And you should make it match multiple subdomains or naked domains (e.g. stackoverflow.com instead of www.stackoverflow.com).

I came up with this `/\A(?:[\w-]+(?<!-)\.){1,}[\w]{2,}\z/`.

Comment: Thank u for help!
When I'm doing VALID_URL_REGEX =(here code from  [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1141962/79835) but I get error 
A regular expression or a proc or lambda must be supplied as :with.
So how I should change this : validates :url, :presence => true, format: { with: VALID_URL_REGEX } ?

Comment: It's to long for comment, I did it like this:
in my application made VALID_URL_REGEX = (the same text as in $search)