# Why can't this regex find text between two markers?

Tags: python, regex

```
str = "{u'xlink:href': u'http://ip/goform/XmlApi?op=ip&port=0&target=1', u'id': u'1'}"
print re.search("/href': u'.*?',/", str)
```

I'm trying to get the text that starts with http:// and ends with target=1 but I'm getting None. Is my regex wrong?

Comment: I don't think you need the / at the beginning and end in python...

Comment: If you want to match a URL with Regex, please see this post for the correct pattern to use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1141962/334053

Comment: deleting the / at the beginning and end solved my problem. But is there a way to not include the two end points in the resulting string?

Comment: @JBernardo: Agreed, Python is not Perl.  Care to unpack that a little?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I think you're searching for the wrong thing (if what you want is the url):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 

import re

if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = "{u'xlink:href': u'http://ip/goform/XmlApi?op=ip&port=0&target=1', u'id': u'1'}"
    m = re.search(r"u'(http://.*?)',", s)
    print m.group(1)
```