# Detect when a URL exists in an element

Tags: jquery, regex

HTML:

```
<textarea name="test">
  http://google.com/
  https://google.com/
  http://www.google.com
  www.google.com/
  [url=http://google.com/]test[/url]
  text
</textarea>
```

jQuery:

```
$('button').click(function() {
    if ($('textarea[name="test"]').val().match(/\[url/)) {
        alert('links exist');
    }
});
```

What kind of regular expressions will match every URL instance I have in my `<textarea>`?

**jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/5Z8AU/

Comment: Why did you give no feedback to the answers on your previous, very similar [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044680/detect-and-remove-urls-from-textarea/15044846#comment21158867_15044846)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more detailed answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url). But if you are looking for a simple Regex that handles only the cases you listed this will do.

```
(http|\[url|www)[^\s]*(/|com|url])
```

It can be understood as this part being the start of the string

```
(http|\[url|www) anything that starts with http, [url, or www
```

Accepting any matching characters that are not a space

```
[^\s]*
```

And this being the end of she string

```
(/|com|url]) anything that ends with /, com, or url]
```