# Parsing a string to extract a URL or folder path

Tags: c#, regex, parsing

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468103/regex-to-parse-a-string-and-match-a-url-or-folder-path/19229533?noredirect=1#19229533) recently about using regex to retrieve a URL or folder path from a string. I was [looking at this comment by Dour High Arch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16468103/regex-to-parse-a-string-and-match-a-url-or-folder-path/19229533?noredirect=1#comment23628386_16468103), where he says:

> "I recommend you do not use regexes at all; use separate code paths
>   for URLs, using the Uri class, and file paths, using the FileInfo
>   class. These classes already handle parsing, matching, extracting
>   components, and so on."

I never really tried this, but now I am looking into it and can't figure out if what he said actually is useful to what I'm trying to accomplish.

I want to be able to parse a string message that could be something like:

> "I placed the files on the server at http://www.thewebsite.com/NewStuff, they can also 
>   be reached on your local network drives at J:\Downloads\NewStuff"

And extract out the two strings `http://www.thewebsite.com/` and `J:\Downloads\NewStuff`. I don't see any methods on the `Uri` or `FileInfo` class that parse a `Uri` or `FileInfo` object from a string like I think Dour High Arch was implying.

Is there something I'm missing about using the `Uri` or `FileInfo` class that will allow this behavior? If not is there some other class in the framework that does this?

Comment: I think what that comment was implying is that if you pass it a file path, etc. It should correct back-slashes for forward-slashes and so forth. I myself would use Regex.

Comment: You were missing Uri.IsWellFormedUriString will return the type of the Uri (including file paths and URLs).  This is the matching mentioned. see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx

Comment: @Hogan If I'm only passing in a string that is a Uri that would be fine. However, I'm asking if there is a method of the Uri or FileInfo class that can accept a string such as the one in the example, and retrieve a URI or Filepath from that string without any further work...

Comment: @Zack - That is easy to answer - "No".

Answer (score 1):

I'd say the easiest way is splitting the strings into parts first.

First delimiter would be spaces, for each word - second would be qoutes (double and single)

Then use Uri.IsWellFormedUriString on each token.

So something like:

```
foreach(var part in String.Split(new char[]{''', '"', ' '}, someRandomText))
{
    if(Uri.IsWellFormedUriString(part, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute))
        doSomethingWith(part);

}
```

Just saw at [URI.IseWellFormedURIString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.iswellformeduristring.aspx) that this is a bit to strickt to suit your needs maybe.
It returns false if www.Whatever.com is missing the http://

Comment: I guess you have to trim other punctuations such as commas, periods, exclamation and question marks, colons, semi-colons and so on,as well, right?

Comment: yeah maybe it would be better to use Regex.Matches instead of string.Split.
So define a more lose regex of what could be a path, then use uri.IsWellFormedUriString to make sure it is.

Answer (score 1):

U can use :

```
(?<type>[^ ]+?:)(?<path>//[^ ]*|\\.+\\[^ ]*)
```

that will give you 2 groups on each result

type : `"http:"`

path : `//www.thewebsite.com/NewStuff`

and

type : `"J:"`

path : `\Downloads\NewStuff`

out of the string

> "I placed the files on the server at
>   http://www.thewebsite.com/NewStuff, they can also be reached on your
>   local network drives at J:\Downloads\NewStuff"

you can use the "type" group to see if the type is `http:`or not and set action on that.

---

EDIT

or use regex below if you are sure there is no whitespace in your filepath :

`(?<type>[^ ]+?:)(?<path>//[^ ]*|\\[^ ]*)`

Answer (score 1):

It was not clear from your earlier question that you wanted to extract URL and file path substrings from larger strings. In that case, neither `Uri.IsWellFormedUriString` nor `rRegex.Match` will do what you want. Indeed, I do not think any simple method can do what you want because you will have to define rules for ambiguous strings like httX://wasThatAUriScheme/andAre/these part/of/aURL or/are they/separate.strings?andIsThis%20a%20Param?

My suggestion is to define a [recursive descent parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9814528/recursive-descent-parser-implementation) and create states for each substring you need to distinguish.

Answer (score -1):

Try `\w+:\S+` and see how well that fits your purposes.