# jQuery regular expression does not validate

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Regular Expression for matching URLs. It should not match the following.

1. www.yammercom
2. http://www.yammer
3. www.yammer..com

**Regular Expression**

```
/^((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)*(www\.)?|((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)(www\.)?)*)[a-z0-9-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/
```

what mistake I am making in my regular expression??

**Try it**

[Rubular demo](http://rubular.com/r/fBGOLqS0jE)

Comment: Can you provide us the free spacing RE？Single line RE is really hard for us to read...

Comment: What do you search for with this: `([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)`

Answer (score 1):

If you need a regex to match a url, you can take a look here:

http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/url-regex

Which you'll find insanely long regex that most will only pass half the test. This should tell you why it's not a good idea to try to validate it in 1 line of regex.

Comment: I've stated the changes on the first line, here is the correct one: http://rubular.com/r/frCdtvj3Vp

Comment: I cant understand what you would like to say?? In the link u have provided http://rubular.com/r/frCdtvj3Vp accepts www.yammer. It is incorrect as per my requirement

Comment: ^((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)*(www\.)?|((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)(www\.)?)*)[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/??$. it seems to work. but 3rd conditon only not  satisfied

Comment: Okay, I just looked at the title and found that the regex was incorrect, I've edited the answer for an expression that matches URL.

Answer (score 1):

After free spacing your RE, it turns out that there are some problems...[image]

You do not need match protocol using `*`, and the last `[]` does not make much sense to me...(maybe you can update your question.)

My tweak is here. See online demo. http://rubular.com/r/12J7ZRo4Qx

```
/^(
    (https?|ftp)
    :\/\/                      #protocol
  )?                           #is optional
  (www\.)?                     #optional www
  [-a-z0-9]+                   #place - first so it means literally
  \.
  [a-z]{2,4}                   #trailing hostname
  (                            #match pathname
    \/                         #a slash is required
    [-a-z0-9]+                 #same as hostname
  )*
/x
```

The `x` flag stands for free-spacing, as in perl.

Anyway, matching url is quite common. My version is not good nor bullet-proofing. It's just for demonstration.
If you need more solid RE, check this http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/8-regular-expressions-you-should-know/.

The book Mastering Regular Expression is another definitive guide

Comment: This question shall also help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url

Comment: ^((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)*(www\.)?|((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)(www\.)?)*)[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2‌​,4}\/??$. it seems to work. but 3rd conditon id not only satisfied

Comment: @Sam `[a-z0-9\-\.]` matches unwanted . in `..com`

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
/^((((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)*(www\.)?|((ht|f)tps?:\/\/)(www\.)?)*)[a-z0-9\-\.]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\/?([^\s<>\#%"\,\{\}\\|\\\^\[\]`]+)?$/
```

You have to scape the `-`