# Replacing multiple links in a string in one line of code in python

Tags: python, regex

I am new to regular expression module. I am trying to remove all the links in a given `exampleString` but in one line of code:

```
exampleSentence = exampleSentence.replace(link for link in re.findall(r'http://*',exampleSentence),'')
```

But I am getting this syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Generator expression must be parenthesized if not sole argument
```

How to proceed with this?

Comment: I think you are missing the list comprehension square brackets!
Can you give you desired input and output clearly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have many issues.

First, [`str.replace()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) replace a sub-string by another in a given string; it does not take generators.

Example:

```
print 'example'.replace('e', 'E')
```

Next, if you want to remove, there is [`re.sub()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
data = re.sub(
  r'[A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9-_]+.[A-Za-z0-9-_:%&;\?#/.=]+', # the URI
  '', # the replacement (nothing here)
  input_data
)
```

The URI regex was copied from [**@miko-trueman** answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31704200/248390).

Comment: Thank you! Makes things easier :)

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is remove all links from a string, you don't need a generator. The following will work.

```
import re
exampleString = "http://google.com is my personal library. I am not one for http://facebook.com, but I am in love with http://stackoverflow.com"
exampleString = re.sub(r"(?:\@|https?\://)\S+", '', exampleString)
```