# React Native, how to turn a comment into a URL?

Tags: url, reactjs, comments, native

I was wondering how I can turn a comment (such as stackoverflow.com) to a post as a URL so that when clicked, it will go straight to the website?

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I think every comment on SO has a permlink...

Comment: For example, my previous comment permlink was: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34931959/#comment57599610_34931959

Comment: I was hoping to spot URLs within a random block of text and make it clickable. For example, if I comment "Search on Google.com" I want to be able to click on Google.com and take me there. Right now "Search on Google.com" shows as just text, no URLs

Answer (score 0):

You can pre-process your text and look for things that might be a URL. Look at this answer here: [Regex to match URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141848/regex-to-match-url).

You'd want to take your text, split it by white-space, then for each white-space-separated word, check if it's a URL. If it's a URL, then output a proper `<a>` tag surrounding it. If not, just output the word.